# How can I fade out, change test and then fade in with jQuery cleanly?

Tags: jquery

I've been playing with a div I have that changes on a user action. I want to have it fade out, change the node value and then fadeIn.

No matter what I try I always see the value change as the element is fading out. Can anyone help?

```
        calculator_result.fadeOut();
        calculator_result.css("color", "#fff").html("&euro;" + vRelief + ".00");
        calculator_result.fadeIn();
```

This is the code I'm using now but I tried it a few different ways! A delay might work but surely these a cleaner way?

Cheers,
Denis

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have the change and the fade in occur in the callback for fadeOut.  When you do it in the callback, the code won't run until after the effect is complete.

```
 calculator_result.fadeOut( 'normal', function() {
      $(this).css("color", "#fff").html("&euro;" + vRelief + ".00" )
             .fadeIn();
 });
```